# How to plot a learning curve based on a sequence of date stamped successes and failures?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

**I have** data on results of surgical operations:

- date of operation (in YYYY-MM-DD format)
- result of operation (0 for successful operation, 1 for unsuccessful operation)

Date is usually used only for case ordering. 
**I need to**

- plot a learning curve. (I had found that the resulting curve called **cumulative average**.) x should be the number of cases y - probability of failure (usually decreases).
- get the data on current performance quality

**The question is:**

- What is the way to achieve this in R (with ggplot2 if possible)?
- Is $\dfrac{successful}{total}*100\%$ will be sufficient statistic for this case or something more advanced is usually required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your dates are in string or factor form, convert them to Dates with `as.Date(DateVariable, format="%Y-%m-%d")` (potentially with an `as.character` around `DateVariable` if it is a factor.

Sort the data.frame with the date and outcome by surgery date.  To get the y variable you describe, the easiest way is to take the cumulative number of outcomes and divide by the number of cases to date (which is just a running sequence from 1 to the number of cases when sorted).  In code:

```
#Make some random data to play with
DF <- data.frame(DateVariable = as.Date(runif(100, 0, 800), origin="2005-01-01"),
    outcome = rbinom(100, 1, 0.1))
#Sort by date
DF <- DF[order(DF$DateVariable),]
DF <- rbind.fill(data.frame(outcome=1),DF)

#Add case numbers (in order, since sorted)
DF$x <- seq(length=nrow(DF))

#Create your definition for y (average to date, which is sum to date divided by number to date)
DF$y <- cumsum(DF$outcome) / DF$x

#Plot it
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point(shape=4) +
geom_point(aes(x,outcome),shape=3) +
stat_smooth(method="loess", se=FALSE, color="darkgreen", size=1) +
scale_y_continuous(name= "Failure rate", limits=c(0, 1)) +
scale_x_continuous(name= "Operations performed")
```

Result:

[image]

(plus marks success and error cases. X - cumulative sum, line - loess curve)

I don't think, however, this is a good metric.  Check out some work on CUSUM curves and risk adjusted CUSUM curves.  CUSUM is just plotting number of (negative) outcomes versus case number; risk adjusted CUSUM assumes you can determine a probability of negative outcome (based on pre-operative variables) and use that to determine if performance is exceeding or lagging expectations.

Comment: Thank you, @Brian. That is exactly the thing I need. I only will further extend it myself  (will add points add smoothed line(loess) ) and add this to your answer with resulting plot, if you don`t mind.

Comment: Found out that the correct plot is drawn only if the first case was failure. Is it possible to assume that at the start the surgeon experience is imperfect?

Comment: @Yuriy, Don't know what makes it incorrect if the first plot is not a failure, but if necessary, you can add `DF <- rbind.fill(data.frame(outcome=1),DF)` before computing `DF$x` and `DF$y`.  But then I question the meaning of what you are really plotting.

Answer (score 6):

An informative "learning curve" will indicate the *current performance* of success.  A cumulative average, however, doesn't do that, because it includes old results along with the new.  When learning truly improves, the cumulative average will be biased low.

**A good solution is to use a [Lowess smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression)** of the response plotted over time.  This robust nonparametric smoother is implemented in many `R` packages: search for the current choices on the [RSeek page](http://www.rseek.org).

As an example, here is a scatterplot of simulated data, their cumulative average, and a Lowess smooth of the data:

[image: Cumulative average]

The green (upper) curve is the Lowess smooth.  (This coding uses 1 for success, 0 for failure, so that an improving curve slopes *upward*.)  **The two curves differ substantially**: the cumulative average barely has a positive slope (about 0.0015) and ends up around 0.5 at the most recent time, whereas the Lowess smooth has a slope around .005 (over three times as great) and ends up around 0.85.  To get a sense of which is correct, consider the most recent responses, say those after time=80: there are 26 of them averaging 0.77.  The Lowess curve is consistent with that level during this period but the cumulative average curve is clearly too low.

(This is a standard exploratory technique to prepare for logistic regression.  If, *on a [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) scale*, the Lowess smooth is approximately linear, then [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) of the response versus time should work well to model the learning curve.  If the smooth is not linear, you could consider logistic regression with [cubic splines](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/splines/html/00Index.html), allowing for changes in slope over time.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `as.POSIXct` to convert to dates, which are stored as seconds from the epoch (and are thus easily plotted) but can be easily displayed in human-readable formats. The help file documents how to import from arbitrary character representations.

Use [geom_line](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_line.html) for plotting. You can use `aggregate` or `by` to bin the observations into days or weeks or whatever. I think ggplot2 has some native functionality for this as well.

I don't know much about learning curves, but I suspect that describing your overall goal more, rather than just the math, would help other people suggest whether the $\frac{successful}{total}$ statistic would tell you what you want to know.