# How to plot a stair steps function with ggplot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I have the graph like this:
[image]

R code for generating it is:

```
DF <- data.frame(date = as.Date(runif(100, 0, 800),origin="2005-01-01"), 
                 outcome = rbinom(100, 1, 0.1))
DF <- DF[order(DF$DateVariable),] #Sort by date
DF$x <- seq(length=nrow(DF)) #Add case numbers (in order, since sorted)
DF$y <- cumsum(DF$outcome)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x,y)) + geom_path() + #Ploting
scale_y_continuous(name= "Number of failures") +
scale_x_continuous(name= "Operations performed")
```

I want something like this:
[image]

The difference is in the form of steps in case of failure (I need rectangular).

My questions are:

- How to achieve this with ggplot2?
- Is there any better option for visualizing failure rate over time/iterations performed?
- What variant is easier to understand: this or [that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14480/how-to-plot-a-learning-curve-based-on-a-sequence-of-date-stamped-successes-and-fa) or, maybe something different?

Comment: Did you look at the on-line help, http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_step.html?

Comment: Yes, this is it. Missed this in documentation.

Comment: @Yuriy, please answer your question. It would help future users with similar problems.

Comment: @mpiktas, added an answer for the main question. Any opinions on other questions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As noted by @chl the answer is simply using [geom_step()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html) instead of geom_path() in the example above.

Result (the plot has different data):

[image]