# How to Assess Linearity assumption of logit in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, model-selection, loess, linearity

In Applied Lineare Regression, (Hosmer, Lemeshow, Sturdivant 3rd ed.) Ch. 4, they present "Purposeful Selection." Part of step 5 is to assess the validity of the linearity assumption of the logit vs the covariates. To do this, they fit their model, and then somehow plot the logit as a continuous function against a continuous covariate to see if it fits the linear model

$$g(\pi) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_2 + \cdots$$

In OLS, one would simply plot the DV against an IV to see if it is appears linear. In logistic regression the DV is dichotomous, so this doesn't work.

Given data where one of the continuous variables is NOT linear with the logit, how do I create an image such as figure 4.1 (p. 114, 3rd ed.)?

[image]

I created a simulation below to demonstrate my issue, and provide a framework of help.

How given that I have fit my simulated data with a simple linear model, how would I take my fitted data and generate a plot that shows the nonlinear nature of the variable `Y`?

### Define parameters

```r
### Size of population
N = 1000

### Create Independent variables
low = 0
high = 5
R = seq(0,5,(high-low)/(N-1))

X = sample(R, N, replace=T)
Y = sample(R, N, replace=T)

### Model parameters
b_0 = -2
b_x = -0.2
b_y = 0.3
```

### Define the model

```r
logit  = b_0 + b_x*X + b_y*(Y+1)*(Y-2)*(Y-4)
p = 1/(1 + exp(-logit))
plot(logit~Y)
```

[image]

#### Sample the data

```r
### Sample the data
Z = rbinom(N, 1, p)
Z = factor(ifelse(Z==0, "No", "Yes"),levels=c("No", "Yes"))

### Create dataframe
df = data.frame(
  X = X,
  Y = Y,
  Z = Z,
  logit = logit,
  p = p
)
```

#### Naive Regression

```r
######  Naive Model
### Perform regression
print(sprintf("b_0: %s, b_x: %s, b_y: %s", b_0, b_x, b_y))
#> [1] "b_0: -2, b_x: -0.2, b_y: 0.3"

logfit = glm(Z ~ Y + X, df, family=binomial)
summary(logfit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Z ~ Y + X, family = binomial, data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -0.8982  -0.7527  -0.6768  -0.5838   1.9656  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -1.00404    0.20164  -4.979 6.38e-07 ***
#> Y            0.07223    0.05162   1.399  0.16175    
#> X           -0.15893    0.05288  -3.006  0.00265 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 1078.6  on 999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 1067.4  on 997  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 1073.4
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

### Plot Y vs predicted logit
predicted_logit = predict(logfit, df)
plot(predicted_logit)
```

[image]

#### "Correct" Regression

```r
##### "Correct" Model

print(sprintf("b_0: %s, b_x: %s, b_y: %s", b_0, b_x, b_y))
#> [1] "b_0: -2, b_x: -0.2, b_y: 0.3"

logfit = glm(Z ~ X + I((Y+1)*(Y-2)*(Y-4)), df, family=binomial)
summary(logfit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Z ~ X + I((Y + 1) * (Y - 2) * (Y - 4)), family = binomial, 
#>     data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.9261  -0.6206  -0.3072  -0.1875   2.8250  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)                    -1.97978    0.20493  -9.661  < 2e-16 ***
#> X                              -0.21401    0.06275  -3.411 0.000648 ***
#> I((Y + 1) * (Y - 2) * (Y - 4))  0.29018    0.02165  13.404  < 2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 1078.55  on 999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance:  777.76  on 997  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 783.76
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

### Plot Y vs predicted logit
predicted_logit = predict(logfit, df)
plot(predicted_logit)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It is unclear how everything after "Load Libraries" bears on your question; and the sheer volume of that material makes your post unsuitable for this site.  Could you explain why all that stuff is necessary for us to read?

Comment: Point taken. The idea is that somehow, I'm supposed to be able to get a plot showing the behavior of the logit relative to Y in the cubic model having only the data to fit, and the simple model. In other words, someone hands me the cubic data, I fit a naive model, and then get a plot like in HLS.

Comment: The title of the figure answers your question: compute a lowess smooth of the $(x,y)$ data and plot it on a logit scale.  I was looking for any of those steps in all your code but couldn't find them, which led me to wonder what your question might be.  See my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14501/919 for a figure and a more detailed description of the process.

Comment: But what data? The y data is dichotomous in the original data. As expected (and shown in the simulation), if I predict from my fit, then, the plot of logit vs y is obviously going to be linear.

Comment: The figure doesn't mention a prediction.  See the graph in the link I added to my previous comment.

Comment: If my DV is a 1 or 0 at each value of the covariate, how do I calculate a "log-odds" to plot against the covariate? Do I fit a loess to the 1s and 0s as in your link? So, kind of treat the DV as continuous [0,1]?

Comment: Step 1: Fit the lowess smooth.  Step 2: compute the logit of the lowess values.

Comment: Got it. I told the first person who told me to do that that it isn't a good idea to plot a factor as a continuous variable :-/  I guess I'll eat my hat.